# Select records with spaces in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column which contains many records with one word in common (e.g Channel names):

```
|        channel        |
--------------------------
| Fox                   |
| Fox Life              |
| Fox News              |
| Fox Action            |
| Fox Movies            |
```

And the search criteria is: "Channel Fox News"

Now I'd like to select the only row that have Fox News.

I've tried so many things, like split the string by spaces, or using LIKE with no success, because the word "Fox" always select all five records.

note that its has to be word level match.

thanks

Comment: show an actual query, because `contains` is not mysql syntax...

Comment: The word `contains` it only an example that what I need, i know that is not a real syntax. (Edited question without query)

Comment: remove word channel from the query, trim spaces, make query like `select * from table where lower(name) = lower('#####'`)

Comment: then what's wrong with using `where channel='Fox News'`?

Comment: Because the query is "Channel Fox News" no just "Fox News"

Comment: What engine for your table?InnoDB or MyIssam?

Comment: I tend to steer well clear of Rupert Murdoch, so I'm going to give this one a miss.

Comment: Engine is InnoDB (MariaDB)

Comment: I can remove the word Channel, but what happened when the search criteria is something like "the channel must be Fox news"

Comment: @garanda so, your question is basically "how to force computer to understand natural speech"?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html See: "'apple banana'

Find rows that contain at least one of the two words."

Comment: Why down vote the question? @MarcB

Comment: I didn't downvote...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This screams for fulltext index

```
ALTER TABLE T add FULLTEXT index(channel);
```

You search with

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE MATCH (channel)
    AGAINST ('+Fox +News' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

plus sign means that word HAS to exist in the column
There are a couple of things you need to pay attention to:

[innodb_ft_min_token_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size)

the minimum size of the word searched

and [stop words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)

Comment: After alter my table with `FULLTEXT` and perform the query with `BOOLEAN MODE` It search exactly in the way I like. This is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `like`?

```
where lower(channel) like '%fox news%'
```

Comment: the query may have more words than just %fox news%, so in this case it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

Just both words with a like should do the trick:

select name from channel where name like '%fox%' and name like '%news%';